# Integration by substitution using implicit function relation

Tags: integration, substitution

When trying to find the integral

$$I = \int (x\sqrt{2x + 5}) \mathrm{d}x$$

if we use the *implicit* substitution $u^2 = 2x + 5$, substituting into the integrand gives the sub-expression $\sqrt{u^2}$.  We usually simplify it to $+u$ and proceed smoothly.  My question is, why don't we consider $-u$ here?

*EDIT*:

I removed the *explicit* substitution, $u = 2x + 5$, let's focus on the implicit one.

Comment: Assuming $x$ is real and therefore $u$ is real, $\sqrt{u^2} = |u|$. [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Properties_and_uses)

Comment: Isn't it that $u>0$?

Answer (score 1):

By definition $\sqrt{x}$ indicates the positive (or [principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Properties_and_uses)) square root of $x$. If we want indicate all the two root we have to write explicitly $\pm\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: I understand this convention.  But here we are dealing with _not_ $\sqrt{x}$, _but_ $\sqrt{x^2}$.  As $x$ inside the square may be positive or negative, we should have $\sqrt{x^2} = \lvert x \rvert = \pm x$ (c.f. @expitt-i-1-z-0's comment).

Answer (score 1):

1. The *implicit* substitution $h(u) = 2x + 5,$ where $u$ is the new
   variable, [is valid for each invertible function
   $h$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2518470/21813).
2. In this case, since $h(u)=u^2,$ it is tacit that $h$ has domain
   $[0,\infty).$

   This is why $\sqrt{u^2}\big(=|u|\big)$ can be simply expressed as
   $u.$
3. Alternatively, we might specify $h$'s domain as $(-\infty,0],$ in
   which case $\sqrt{u^2}=-u$.