# Substitution: why can we ignore the absolute value in this case?

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I am trying to solve this integral:

$$\int\frac{dx}{x(3+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

We can use substitution:$$1-x^2=u^2$$ and $$-x dx=u du$$
Which gives us:
$$-\int\frac{udu}{(1-u^2)(4-u^2)|u|}$$

Now my calculus-book then just proceeds saying this integral equals:

$$-\int\frac{du}{(1-u^2)(4-u^2)}$$

**Question: why can we just ignore the absolute value in this case?**

Couldn't $u$ be both $+\sqrt{1-x^2}$ or $-\sqrt{1-x^2}$? I was expecting to make two separate cases, one for $u<0$ and one for $u\ge0$. Why is this not so?

---

EDIT: Perhaps the mistake that I made is that the real substitution isn't $1-x^2=u^2$, but $u=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, which is positive?

Comment: That is because $\sqrt A$ denotes the non-negative square root of the non-negative number $A$.

Comment: It is assumed that $u\ge0$. Otherwise it is not well-defined by means of equation $1-x^2=u^2$.

Comment: If all you know is that $1-x^2=u^2$ couldn't $u$ then be both $+\sqrt{1-x^2}$ or $-\sqrt{1-x^2}$?

Comment: See the comment above. Of course you are free to choose either of the forms. But you cannot choose both of them.

Comment: @user That was what I was commenting about, I don't see what you mean by not "well-defined"

Comment: @Bernard if you are solving $1-x^2=u^2$ for $u$ then there are two solutions right? Why don't we see both solutions back in the substitution?

Comment: I mean that the map $x\mapsto u$ should be one-valued. Imagine you are going to compute definite integral from $x_1$ to $x_2$. Could you choose $u_1=\sqrt{1-x_1^2}$, $u_2=-\sqrt{1-x_2^2}$?

Comment: @GambitSquared Bernard hit the nail on the head.  Suppose that you were asked to evaluate $\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{x^2} dx.$  You would assume that if $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2},$ then $f(x)$ is a **non-negative** function  throughout the interval $[-1,1].$

Comment: @user2661923 Exactly for that reason you cannot say that $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2}=x$ for the whole domain. For $x<0$ then $f(x)=-x$

Comment: @GambitSquared Agreed.  Therefore, **by convention** $f(x)$ (in my example) is **construed** to represent $|x|,$ which is the point that Bernard was making in the first place.

Comment: My answer is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4370753/21813).

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\int{\dd x \over x\pars{3 + x^{2}}\root{1 -x^{2}}} =
> {1 \over 3}\int{\dd x \over x\root{1 - x^{2}}} -
> {1 \over 3}\int{x \over \pars{3 + x^{2}}\root{1 - x^{2}}}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

\begin{align}
{1 \over 3}\int{\dd x \over x\root{1 - x^{2}}} &
\,\,\,\stackrel{x\ =\ 1/t}{=}\,\,\,
-\,{1 \over 3}\int{\dd t \over \root{t^{2} - 1}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{t\ =\ \sec\pars{\theta}}{=}\,\,\,
-\,{1 \over 3}\int\sec\pars{\theta}\,\dd \theta
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 3}\,\ln\pars{\verts{\sec\pars{\theta} + \tan\pars{\theta}}} =
-\,{1 \over 3}\,\ln\pars{\verts{t + \root{t^{2} - 1}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 3}\ln\pars{\verts{x \over 1 + \root{1 - x^{2}}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 6}\bracks{\ln\pars{\verts{x \over 1 + \root{1 - x^{2}}}} +
\ln\pars{\verts{1 - \root{1 - x^{2}} \over x}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 6}\,\ln\pars{\verts{1 - \root{1 - x^{2}} \over
1 + \root{1 - x^{2}}}}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
{1 \over 3}\int{x \over \pars{3 + x^{2}}\root{1 - x^{2}}}\,\dd x &
\,\,\,\stackrel{x\ =\ \root{1 - t^{2}}}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over 3}\int{\dd t \over t^{2} - 4} =
{1 \over 12}\int\pars{{1 \over t - 2} - {1 \over t + 2}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 12}\ln\pars{\verts{t - 2 \over t + 2}} =
\bbx{-\,{1 \over 12}\ln\pars{\verts{\root{1 - x^{2}} + 2 \over
\root{1 - x^{2}} - 2}}}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\int{\dd x \over x\pars{3 + x^{2}}\root{1 -x^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{%
{1 \over 6}\ln\pars{\verts{1 - \root{1 - x^{2}} \over 1 + \root{1 - x^{2}}}} +
{1 \over 12}\ln\pars{\verts{\root{1 - x^{2}} + 2 \over \root{1 - x^{2}} - 2}} + \mbox{a constant}}
\end{align}

Comment: Are you sure this is the right answer? It doesn't have any real values because of $\sqrt{1-x^2}-2$ My calculus-book gives the answer: $\frac{1}{6}\log |\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}|+\frac{1}{12}\log |\frac{2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2-\sqrt{1-x^2}}|+C$ But anyway my real question was why we can get rid of the absolute sign...

Comment: @GambitSquared Done. Thanks.