# why is the following U-Substitution wrong?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, real-numbers, substitution

It is known that

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx = arcsin(x)+c$$

this can be done utilizing u-substitution $ x = sin(u) $

However,

i can let $  u = 1-x^2 $

$dx = -2u \, du $

which gives the integral

$$ -\int \frac{2u}{\sqrt{u}} du $$

which then returns $$ \frac{-4\sqrt{u^3}}{3} $$

which is clearly wrong.

So why is this wrong?

thanks very much for your help and apologies about the elementary 
question.

REMARK

Upon checking other posts , a common problem has to do with the range of the function being substituted in.

Example

[What is wrong with the following u-substitution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929380/what-is-wrong-with-the-following-u-substitution)

Comment: If $  u = 1-x^2 $   then $d\color{red}u = -2\color{red}x d\color{red}x$

Comment: Your differentials are incorrect.  With your u-sub $du = -2xdx$.  This is not the same as $dx = -2udu$.  I don't think that a u-sub is possible here.  This is just a well-known integral, which is known based on the fact that the derivative of $\sin^{-1}(x) = 1/(\sqrt{1-x^2})$.

Answer (score 1):

Your alternative method is incorrect, because if $u=1-x^2$ then $du=-2x\,dx$.

You wrote $dx=-2u\,du$; that is different.